# Floating point modulus precision (high multiple)

Tags: numerical-methods, online-resources, wolfram-alpha, floating-point

While looking at implementing floating point modulus in double-precision on an x86 CPU, I found the [FPREM](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_107.html) instruction and proceeded to test the practical precision in some cases, one being

```
1e48 mod 1.5
```

The FPREM implementation returns 1 as result, which looked "right" to me (as 1e48 is not a multiple of 3).

Then I checked against Wolfram Alpha but it returned 0  (http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1e48+mod+1.5%29)... now I am having doubts, is Wolfram failing or are FPREM and my expectation wrong?

Also in case Wolfram is failing, is there an online high-precision resource I could use to compare floating point modulus precision?

Comment: Even Wolfram Alpha shows 1 if you use the definition $x \pmod y = x-\lfloor\frac{x}{y}\rfloor y$,
e.g. if you enter `10^48-floor(10^48/1.5)*1.5`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The true value of $10^n$ mod $1.5$ is $1$ for all positive integers $n$. Wolfram Alpha gets it right for $n \le 16$, and wrong for (it seems) all $n \ge 17$.

Wolfram Alpha gets `1e17 mod 3` right, but `1e17 mod 3.0` wrong. So a loss of floating-point precision is to blame.

Answer (score 1):

It might be worth pointing out that you *can* use WolframAlpha to get the correct result by simply specifying greater precision.  You can specify 1.5 to 50 digits of precision like so: 1.5`50.  So your query would be:

[1e48 mod 1.5`50](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1e48+mod+1.5%6050)

You can even specify *exact* precision:

[1e48 mod 3/2](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1e48+mod+3%2F2)

Comment: Interesting, is there a reference about WolframAlpha custom precedence rules? "1e48 mod 3/2" is understood as "(1e48 mod 3)/2" under usual precedence rules, which place modulus alongside multiplication & division, with a left-associativity.

Comment: @Eric I agree, but I don't think it's just a simple matter of precedence. Keep in mind, the vision of WolframAlpha is not to be a calculator but to actually understand natural language. In that context, "mod" is a word and the input `mod` returns information about the 1960s British subculture with four alternative possibilities. Given this broad objective, WA really can't look at your input and jump straight to evaluation. Furthermore, "1e48 mod 3/2" is not valid Mathematica syntax; the natural language parser parses it to `Mod[10^48,3/2]`. A similar thing happens for "1e48 mod 3+2", in fact.

Comment: I get your point, but by that natural language interpretation "3-1 multiplied by 4" should be understood as "(3-1) * 4" but WA interprets it as "3 - 1*4", applying regular precedence (this also illustrates that natural language is quite ambiguous and unusable mathematically-speaking), so this look more like a plain old bug for precedence of modulo

Comment: @Eric I'm not sure I agree with your interpretation of "3-1 multiplied by 4"; I don't see why we wouldn't assume that multiplication should take precedence over subtraction. I guess this ambiguity is exactly why natural language is difficult to deal with. To be clear, though, the point of my original comment was not to indicate that the interpretation *should* be one way or another but simply to source of the discrepancy.